# Phase of type 3 compensator

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis

I was supposed to simulate a type3 compensator but i got different result from PSPICE and HSPICE.I have no idea why??:(

[image]

PSPICE:[image]

HSPICE: shape of gain is the same with PSPICE,but shape of phase changes like below.(I dont have the simulation result pic but just like this)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the HSPICE output is for the same exact circuit?  That phase characteristic looks artificial to me.  The PSPICE simulation seems to match what is in this document: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva662/slva662.pdf

Comment: They are the same. One has been normalised to +/-180 phase, other shows the phase in extended range.

Comment: @user_1818839  Ahhh.  I see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape of phase are the same.
Just limited to +180°/-180° (with wrap around).

Here is what I get with [microcap v12](https://spectrum-soft.com)

[image]

Comment: thank u very much!!!